# Derived category and L-function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

For abelian varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$ $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{A}'$, if derived categories $D(\mathscr{A})$ and $D(\mathscr{A}')$ are equivalent then L-functions are same $L(s,\mathscr{A})=L(s,\mathscr{A}')$.

Is this true for any smooth projective varieties? In other words, for smooth projective varieties $X$ and $Y$, $D(X)\simeq D(Y)$ then $L(s,H^i(X))=L(s,H^i(Y))$ ?

Comment: It would be nice if you explain what are $L$-functions of abelian categories and what are $L$-functions of cohomology groups.

Comment: Thank you  Sasha. Definition is here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144285/l-functions-of-varieties-zeta-functions-of-their-models,  and for an Abelian variety $\mathscr{A}$, we set $L(s,\mathscr{A}):= L(s,H^1(\mathscr{A}))$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In fact, I am sure this is not known. One of the reasons is the following. I guess (correct me if I am wrong) one can extract the Betti number $b_i(X)$ from the $L$-function $L(s,H^i(X))$ (as its value at some point, or as the value of its derivative at some point), but it is not known (although conjectured) that $b_i(X)$ is a derived invariant.

Comment: Is it possible for the infinity version of the derived category? If you can compute the Hochschild homology of the category over Q with the S1 action it may be possible to calculate algebraic de rham cohomology from it?

Comment: @AndyJiang: I have no idea about that. Do you have some reference?

Comment: Dear Jiang, I think if the dimension of smooth varieties is less than 3 then we can compute algebraic de rham cohomology by using Hochschild homology. I will add a reference.

Comment: Dear Sasha, thank your reply. You are right. By the way, in my understanding, canonical bundle is characterized by derived category (Bondal-Orlov?), so $H^i(X,K_X)$ are derived invariants. What is a difficulty to characterize cotangent bundle by derived category?

Comment: @user145752: The difficulty is just that nobody knows how to do this.

Comment: @sasha Someone else can probably say this better but you can look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05246 in the case of smooth Q algebra I think everything is very nice and you can basically read off de rham cohomology. I'm working over the infinity version of the derived category though. Note that Hochschild is an invariant of the derived category I believe.

Comment: @AndyJiang: I see that in this reference certain filtrations are constructed, but I don't see there any claim about their invariance under derived equivalences. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Sasha so it's my fault because I can't find a good reference but I think what happens is that the Hochschild homology can be constructed as the trace of the identity of the derived category. So HH(X/Q) with the S1 action should be functorial in the infinity derived category of X. Then in the smooth rational case I think all the filtrations are split canonically coming from sort of the eigenvalues of the map double cover S1 - >S1. More concretely the homotopy groups of HH will be differential forms with the S1 action providing the differentials (because of HKR in the smooth case)